# JavaScript Chrome Problem

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typeerror, uncaught-exception

I've this script:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function init(){

var extText = window.frames.messageTxt.document.body.lastChild.lastChild.data;
extText = extText.replace(/[\r\n]/g," ");
document.forms[0].nMessage.value = extText;
}

window.onload=init;

</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe name='messageTxt' src='lineData.txt' style='display:none'></iframe>
<form>
<textarea name='nMessage'></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code open a file (now lineData.txt) and put it on a textarea. This code works on Firefox and IE but doesn't work on Chrome.

The problem is on

```
window.frames.messageTxt.document.body.lastChild.lastChild.data;
```

The console tell me in that line:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

How can I do to make it works on Chrome ?

Comment: It works for me in Chrome12. Can you set up an example that doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 2):

If you are testing locally (eg file://C:/.../test.html) you won't be able to properly access frames/iframes in Chrome.

Comment: @Diego Stamigni Chrome does not treat all local files as being from the same domain; instead, it thinks they're all distinctly different. Therefore, the default security policy does not allow access.  If you want to do that, you can start Chrome with the command-line option "--allow-file-access-from-files". You have to make sure you completely stop all Chrome processes before starting up a new one with that flag.